# Growth over time with variable growth rate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

X increases Y + Z times per time unit:

```
X = X + (time * (Y + Z) )
```

The value of Z is constant Z = 1, value of Y starts at Y = 2.0 and is decaying at speed of 0.5 per time unit.

Is it possible to use equation to predicate the value of X after N time units, witch the assumption that Y (growth rate) could have reached zero somewhere in mid of time-frame?

Example: time T = 6

```
0 - growth = 1 + 2.0
1 - growth = 1 + 1.5
2 - growth = 1 + 1.0
3 - growth = 1 + 0.5
4 - growth = 1
5 - growth = 1
6 - growth = 1
```

Is it possible to show it with math equation?

Comment: It will be $$(T+1)(Z+Y)-0.5\sum_{k=0}^{\min(\lfloor Y/0.5\rfloor ,T)}k.$$ If $N=\min(\lfloor Y/0.5\rfloor,T)$ this will give a result of $$(T+1)(X+Y)-0.5\cdot \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$

Comment: This assumes the decay is not continuous, which would make the formula a little more difficult.